# optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException when persisting a record with Spring Data's CrudRepository

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data, optimistic-locking

I just learned Hibernate's optimistic locking last week and introduced it to my application written with Spring JPA and MySQL DB.

My Entity looks like this, the `Version` annotation was just added,

```
@Entity    
public class Instance { 
    ...

    @javax.persistence.Version
    private Date updateTime;

    ...

    pubic Instance() {
        this.updateTime = new Date();
    }

}
```

And I have a `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` used for persisting the data. While I verified updating existing record works fine, the problem is it'll throw exception when persisting a new object,

```
inst = new Inst(); 
instanceRepo.save(inst);
```

The exception thrown is

```
org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [Instance] with identifier [a5deddb9-d76c-433f-8b0d-e50cbf8f601e]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : 
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2541)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3285)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.save(Unknown Source)
```

This is simply the first persistence call and I don't think there are multiple threads trying to update this record, so I'm confused why this exception is thrown.

Also I tried to trace into the underlying code, and here is some findings might be helpful,

1. When calling the underlying `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository#save(S)` as pasted below, the code will go to the merge logic even though this is a new record,

   `public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
       if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
           em.persist(entity);
           return entity;
       } else {
           return em.merge(entity);
       }
   }`
2. The exception happens when it tries to commit the transaction and flush the DB.

Comment: isn't that what is supposed to happen in case you have an stale object .. that's why we use optimistic locking?

Answer (score 2):

The JPA spec said that
`The following types are supported for version properties: int, Integer, short, Short, long, Long, java.sql.Timestamp.`

There may be problem when you use java.util.Date type.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this and tried the method suggested by @Zulfi, but didn't work either.

Comment: As i understand, the @Version field will be updated by the JPA engine itself. so in your code you should not set value for @ Version field, not init its value as well. Try to remove this this.updateTime = new Date();

Answer (score 1):

@Version annotation can also be used for Date Fields if your JPA provider supports that .But You would have to map the date field with @Temporal annotation too as below

```
@javax.persistence.Version
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updateTime;
```

For more details please visit below link

http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jpa-entity-versioning-version-and-optimistic-locking

Comment: Thanks for answering, I actually found this usage yesterday and tried this exact same thing, but somehow it didn't work out as expected. I traced into the `save` call but found when it tries to determine the `version` type it still gets `Date` instead of `TIMESTAMP`, and the same error still shows up. Do you know why?